# ACM Graphics, Moving an image across the screen

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I can't get my code to compile. I'm Trying to get an Image to move across the screen by using a timer. Can I get some help? It there is a background gif that i have working, and a png of an turtle is supposed to move across the screen but I can't get it to work.

Here is the beginning of my class (it all compiles and works):

```
  class BackGroundPanel extends JFrame{
 private Image backGround, theImage;
 Dimension screenSize;
 int width;
 int height; 
 private URL myCodeBase;
 private Turtle turtle1;

 JPanel mainPanel;
 public BackGroundPanel(String bgImg, String theImage) {
      //super();
      backGround = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(bgImg);
      this.theImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(theImage);
      mainPanel =  new JPanel();
      screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      height = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
      width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
      mainPanel.setLayout(null);
      setSize(width, height);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setResizable(false);
      setVisible(true);
      add(mainPanel);

 }
```

Here is my paint method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

      g.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, width, height, this);
      int x=700;

      int y=700;


     final int num = 0;
     final JPanel pane;
     Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener()
     {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     num++;
     pane.repaint();
     }
     });

     pane = new JPanel() {
     @Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawImage(theImage, x, y, this);
     }
     };
     timer.start();

 }

 public void setBackGroundImage(Image backGround) {
      this.backGround = backGround;    
 }

 private Image getBackGroundImage() {
      return backGround;    
 }
```

I get the errors:

```
GTurtleFly_Tester.java:71: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
     Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener()
                             ^ 


GTurtleFly_Tester.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
     timer.start();
          ^
```

symbol:   method start()

Comment: If you get an error (which I assume is what you mean why you say "can't compile"), you should post the exact error message in the question. If there's no error but it's not doing what you want, post expected along with actual output in the question. Also please post a [mcve] (this is neither minimal nor complete).

Comment: `Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener())` Which `Timer` class is it? The compiler tells you exactly what the problem is: you're using an `int` instead of a `String`.